# Autofac modules declare required registrations

Tags: autofac

Is it possible for Autofac modules to declare registrations that it depends on?

It would be nice of Autofac could validate that these dependencies are fulfilled before a further runtime error.

The idea comes from one of Java's dependency injection framework, Guice which has a [requireBinding](http://google.github.io/guice/api-docs/latest/javadoc/com/google/inject/AbstractModule.html#requireBinding-java.lang.Class-) function within its modules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[Autofac modules](http://autofac.readthedocs.org/en/latest/configuration/modules.html) do not support the ability to declare their "requirements".** Given the flexible nature of Autofac with the ability to provide dynamic registration sources and such, providing a function like `requireBinding` would require quite a bit of change to the internals of Autofac. (It is for this same reason that Autofac can't analyze potential object resolution failures at runtime without actually resolving the objects in question.)